# Ошибка "date: extra operand" при преобразовании в unixtime

Tags: linux, bash, дата

Пытаюсь в `bash` преобразовать строку вида `2017-07-05 06:00:00` скриптом в `unixtime`, но получаю ошибку:

```
date: extra operand `+%s'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

Хотя из командной строки всё получается без ошибок.

Пример скрипта:

```
!#/bin/bash
DT="2017-07-05 06:00:00"
date --date=$DT +"%s"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Кавычки забыли - `date --date="$DT" +"%s"`

Comment: @0xdb огромное спасибо, теперь всё как надо! Заработался, допустил глупую ошибки :(

Comment: Пожалуйста! Отдыхать всё-таки полезно.

Comment: @0xdb, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy Давно задавался вопросом - стоит ли отвечать на вопросы, где допущены ошибки по невнимательности, на пр. забытая запятая?

Comment: @0xdb, пропущенные кавычки - это не невнимательность, а одна из самых распространённых ошибок. В данном случае точно стоит.

Answer (score 2):

Переменная `DT` содержит пробелы, поэтому `date` воспринимает её остаток после первого пробела как дополнительные параметры. Чтобы избежать, заключите переменную в кавычки.

> Хотя из командной строки всё получается без ошибок.

Нет, в командной строке будет таже ошибка:

```
~$ DT="2017-07-05 06:00:00"
~$ date --date=$DT +"%s"
date: extra operand ‘+%s’
```

А так работает:

```
~$ date --date="$DT" +"%s"
1499227200
```